# Minecraft 1.13.2 crash when I hit play

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Every time I hit play on the launcher it tries to open then crashes.

I am using Windows 10 professional 64 bit; I have uninstalled and reinstalled both Java and Minecraft.

Here is the error log:

> ---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // Hi. I'm Minecraft, and I'm a
>   crashaholic.
>
> Time: 29/03/19 09:57 م Description: Initializing game
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver
>   does not appear to support OpenGL     at cgd.b(SourceFile:218)    at
>   cgd$$Lambda$853/1962688455.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
>     at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)   at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1649)     at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1827)  at
>   cgd.(SourceFile:99)     at cgc.a(SourceFile:79)     at
>   cft.am(SourceFile:439)    at cft.a(SourceFile:380)    at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)
>
> A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known
>
> ### details is as follows:
>
> -- Head -- Thread: Client thread Stacktrace:  at cgd.b(SourceFile:218)    at cgd$$Lambda$853/1962688455.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
>     at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)   at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1649)     at
>   org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1827)  at
>   cgd.(SourceFile:99)     at cgc.a(SourceFile:79)     at
>   cft.am(SourceFile:439)
>
> -- Initialization -- Details: Stacktrace:     at cft.a(SourceFile:380)    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)
>
> -- System Details -- Details:     Minecraft Version: 1.13.2   Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0   Java Version: 1.8.0_51,
>   Oracle Corporation    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation  Memory: 641696776 bytes (611 MB) /
>   805306368 bytes (768 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)     JVM Flags:
>   9 total;
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
>   -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M  Launched Version: 1.13.2    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14   OpenGL: NO CONTEXT  GL Caps:    Using VBOs: No  Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client
>   brand is untouched.   Type: Client (map_client.txt)   Resource Packs:
>   Faithful+1.12.2-rv4   Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException:
>   null  Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)   CPU:

Comment: Post your system specs (CPU, GPU, RAM amount). From just the logs the problem isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest driver for your video card - the log states that the required OpenGL version isn't supported.